# How to declare a ListIterator that perserves its refrence value?

Tags: java

I am calling displayNextPhoto from main class using an instance variable of class Album that contains the displayNextPhoto method. whenever i call this method from the main i get a conccurent modification exception. how can i solve this problem.
I know that whenever i call this function the listIterator variable will be initialized and i will always display the first photo , is there a way to keep the listIterator perserving its value whenever i call this method so that i can avoid re-initialization for that iterator.

```
     public void displayNextPhoto(){
            ListIterator<Photo> listIterator = photos.listIterator();
           if(listIterator.hasNext()){
                Photo photo = listIterator.next();
                System.out.println("Displaying "+photo.getName()+" on "+photo.getDate());
                goingForward = true;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("End of album");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

listIterator() also has an overloaded version that accepts an int input specifying the starting index.

So if you wanted to begin at the index of 2, you could declare it as follows:

```java
ListIterator<Photo> listIterator = photos.listIterator(2);
```

You would need to keep track of your index position in one of your objects, perhaps in the album object, and then add it as a parameter of displayNextPhoto()

```java
public void displayNextPhoto(int i){
    ListIterator<Photo> listIterator = photos.listIterator(i);
    if(listIterator.hasNext()){
        Photo photo = listIterator.next();
        System.out.println("Displaying "+photo.getName()+" on "+photo.getDate());
        goingForward = true;
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("End of album");
    }
}
```

That being said, if you are going to be modifying a class to include a field storing the iterator's current index, you could also just use an ordinary ArrayList and forget about using ListIterator.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
List<Photo> photos;
ListIterator<Photo> listIterator;

public Construct() {
    photos = new ArrayList<>();// init it.
    listIterator = photos.listIterator();
}

public void displayNextPhoto() {
    if (listIterator.hasNext()) {
        Photo photo = listIterator.next();
        // do something
    } else {
        System.out.println("End of album");
    }
}
```

Comment: If i did put  ListIterator<Photo> listIterator = photos.listIterator(); before the constructor that would give me a null pointer exception. If i defined that in the constructor i will get a conccurent modification error

Comment: Edited a sample, no exception occurred.